# Location of negative of a given complex number.

Tags: complex-numbers

Suppose, a complex number $z$ is given. Then, $-z$ should be the mirror image about the origin.

The other way round, if $z$ triggers a rotation by $x$ degrees in the anticlockwise direction, $-z$ should trigger a clockwise $x$ degrees rotation.

Depending on the choice of $z$, figuring out $-z$ by either of the methods, we won't always end up getting the same $-z$ in the argand plane.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z=re^{i\theta}$ is interpretted as an operator that rotates a complex number by an angle $\theta$ and scales it by $r$, then $-z$ does **not** simply rotate the complex number by $-\theta$.

The first statement you give in regards to $-z$ is correct: it is the reflection through the origin of $z$ in the Argand plane.

Answer (score 0):

" The other way round, if z triggers a rotation by x degrees in the anticlockwise direction, -z should trigger a clockwise x degrees rotation."

This is false. This corresponds to just negating the imaginary part.